# Array with List as Element

Tags: c, arrays, list

I am currently making a Library simulation program where the `Index` of the array is the `BookID` of books available.

What I want to do is assign a linked-list / clist to every `Index` of the array so I can store which `borrowerID` has loaned out specific books.

I have all of the `CList` library files and to create a `CList` I can type the following code.

```
clist *xs;
xs = new_clist();
```

My array is currently

```
borrower[1000];
```

For each index I want to add create a `new_clist()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
clist* borrower[1000];
int i;
for(i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    borrower[i] = new_clist();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really trying to get my head around pointers. Pointers seem to be my down point at the moment and I can't seem to visualise them very well.

Comment: You're welcome. Check http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ for additional information.